# Python writing one character per line instead of entire string on temporary file

Tags: python, string, temporary-files, txt

I am trying to **write and read** a string onto a temproary file, but when I print each line in the string, it outputs only one character per line (I assume it's because when I run the for loop, it recognizes each "line" of the string as an individual character.

Below is a snippet of my string `division_text` if I just perform a `print(division_text)`:

```
Locked VersoToken Tokens- 170,833.00 VSO
LOCKED
Locked 05/02/2021 • Unlocks 10/01/2022
Owner: 0x308D2Ac1Bab7D0211717F969602fBC26D286555A
UNLOCK COUNTDOWN
352D – 9H – 10M – 29S
```

And below is what is being written into the tmp file:

```
L
o
c
k
e
d

V
e
r
s
o
T
o
k
e
n
.
.
.
```

My code is below:

```
division_text = 'Locked VersoToken Tokens- 170,833.00 VSO
LOCKED
Locked 05/02/2021 • Unlocks 10/01/2022
Owner: 0x308D2Ac1Bab7D0211717F969602fBC26D286555A
UNLOCK COUNTDOWN
352D – 9H – 10M – 29S
VIEW TX'

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False) as tmp:
    print(tmp.name)
    tmp.write('{}\n'.format(division_text))
    
# reopen the file for reading
with open(tmp.name) as tmp:
    new_division_text = tmp.read()
    for line in new_division_text:
        print(line)

os.remove(tmp.name)
```

The output of `print(line)` is the vertical series of characters I wrote above.

The `'{}\n'.format(division_text)` doesn't seem to be helping in anything.

I cannot modify the string into a list of lines because then I can't write a list into a file as if it were a .txt file I'd read from. Or could I?

And how does Python/my computer know it is a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read()` reads the entire contents of a file into a single array, that's why when you are iterating through it it prints each character on a separate line.

you need something like:

```
with open(tmp.name) as tmp:
    new_division_text = tmp.readlines()
    for line in new_division_text:
        print(line)
```

note the `readlines()`